# How to get istanbul coverage reports for a JavaScript/QUnit project?

Tags: javascript, qunit, istanbul

I have a minimal browser JavaScript project using QUnit which I wrote using the example provided by QUnit docs. Here is the source code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit-2.6.2.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
  <script src="qunit-2.6.2.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**example.js**

```
/**
 * Returns a sum of two numbers
 *
 * @param {number} - first number
 * @param {number} - second number
 *
 * @returns {number}
 */
function mysum(arg1, arg2) {

    var ret;

    ret = arg1 + arg2;

    return ret;
}

mysum(1, 2);
```

**tests.js**

```
QUnit.test( "hello test", function( assert ) {
  assert.ok( 1 == "1", "Passed!" );
});

QUnit.test( "mysum test", function( assert ) {
  assert.ok( mysum(1, 2) == 3, "Passed!" );
});
```

Tests run fine when I open **index.html** in the browser. My goal is to add coverage reports before I start extending it. First I wanted to use [Blanket.js](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket), because it promises to work with QUnit. I tried to reproduce the steps described in their [getting started](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/docs/getting_started_browser.md) tutorial but it didn't work (I saw no added coverage related content in the browser) and I couldn't figure out what's wrong (there was no content in the browser's JavaScript console). However, **Blanket.js** claims to be unmaintained and recommends [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/). As I understand from its README, **istanbul cover** is for node scripts (my project is browser only) and **istanbul instrument . -o coverage** just generates a directory with JavaScript source code files only and I have no idea what to do with them.

How to get HTML coverage reports like [these](https://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/public/coverage/lcov-report/index.html) for my project using **Istanbul**?

Comment: I know this is old but did you ever figure this out?